# Plot irregular intervals (Y axis) with R

Tags: r, axis, intervals

I'm new with R and I'd like to create a plot with irregular intervals like the second one already suggested on another discussion ([Uneven axis in base r plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548075/uneven-axis-in-base-r-plot#comment103805827_58548075)). I'm not able to run the given script with my data.

I'd like to add more space between each Y label from 0 to 2000.
I'd also like to have less space between each Y label from 2000 to 7000. This would help me to distinguish the different lines in my graph that are really close to each other.

I don't want to use the ggplot function if it is possible.

Thanks a lot!!

Here what I've done (see my graph):
`axis(2, c(seq(0, 2000, by=250), seq(2000,7000, by = 1000)), las = 1)`

[My actual graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moHGE.png)